# AS3 post xml ULRequest

Tags: actionscript-3

I am having trouble posting an xml file with the URLLoader.

After it loads it seems that there is no XML attached to the request, could any 
please clarify what i am doing wrong here (banging head against the wall)

// code

```
private function postXmlFiles():void
{
          var a:XML = new XML(new EmbeddedXML());

          var r:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://vms.api.apic.co/rest/v3/addmedia");

          r.data  = a;
          r.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
          r.contentType = "text/xml";

          l = new URLLoader();
          l.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

         //  Handlers  
      l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_complete);  

      l.load(r);
}       

    private function on_complete(e : Event):void
    {  
        trace('loaded!:' + l.data); // this is returning "loaded!: No xml file attached to the request."
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, replacing one string:

```
var a:XML = new XML("<test/>");
```

Trace output changed, indicating `l.data` field actually contains something.
I also used debugging proxy, and examined request body, it does contained my `<test/>` string.

You should test your `new EmbeddedXML()` call to see what it returns.